# Decode Hex Timestamp, probably filetime

Tags: go, timestamp, filetime

im struggling with a timestamp i want to convert to human readable format, it is from OPCUA protocol and is supposed to be in hundreds of nanoseconds since 1. Jan 1601, so it should be filetime. However, trying various solutions posted here i am not able to convert it to the right time.

Here are some examples,

```
1c67dc4ab30dd201 -> Sep 13, 2016 13:38:05.343106800 CET 
15605a199070d201 -> Jan 17, 2017 08:05:35.012046900 CET 
322b4f629970d201 -> Jan 17, 2017 09:12:02.882846600 CET
```

As wireshark is able to decode it there must be a way, maybe someone is able and willing to tell me which steps are necessary to do it.

Comment: It seems it is using In little endian, you store the least significant byte in the smallest address. Reverse it byte by byte and normalize the nano seconds with 1970 ,1601 difference

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the OPCUA protocol, but your hexa timestamps can be converted to Go timetamps like this:

First, the bytes of the timestamps have to be read **backward** (different byteorder than you used).

So instead of these:

```
0x1c67dc4ab30dd201, 0x15605a199070d201, 0x322b4f629970d201
```

You have to reverse the bytes and work with these:

```
0x01d20db34adc671c, 0x01d27090195a6015, 0x01d27099624f2b32
```

Next, these values are in **10-microsecond unit**, so to get nanoseconds, multiply by 100.

And last, the offset is **369 years** compared to Epoch, which is January 1, 1970 UTC.

The final conversion:

```
var delta = time.Date(1970-369, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC).UnixNano()

func convert(t int64) time.Time {
    // reverse bytes:
    var t2 int64
    for i := 0; i < 8; i, t = i+1, t>>8 {
        t2 = t2<<8 | t&0xff
    }

    return time.Unix(0, t2*100+delta)
}
```

Testing it:

```
// If you want results in CET:
cet, err := time.LoadLocation("CET")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

ts := []int64{0x1c67dc4ab30dd201, 0x15605a199070d201, 0x322b4f629970d201}
for _, t := range ts {
    fmt.Println(convert(t).In(cet))
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/yEXwYoK21l)):

```
2016-09-13 13:38:05.3431068 +0200 CEST
2017-01-17 08:05:35.0120469 +0100 CET
2017-01-17 09:12:02.8828466 +0100 CET
```

### Processing `[]byte` input

If the timestamp is handed to you as a byte slice (`[]byte`), or you have an [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) from which you can read a byte slice, you don't need that byte-reversal loop; you can use the following converter function:

```
func convert2(data []byte) time.Time {
    t := binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(data)
    return time.Unix(0, int64(t)*100+delta)
}
```

Testing it:

```
data := []byte{0x32, 0x2b, 0x4f, 0x62, 0x99, 0x70, 0xd2, 0x01}
fmt.Println(convert2(data).In(cet))
```

Output (this one is also in the [Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/yEXwYoK21l) linked above):

```
2017-01-17 09:12:02.8828466 +0100 CET
```

Comment: good work, 1c67dc4ab30dd201 is not hex rather they are byte arrays only .It would be better if the program is updated with that

Comment: @Sarathsp Yeah, I agree, but the asker provided hexa numbers, so that's what I started from.

Comment: makes sense. I wonder if this `endianness`  a part of the protocol or thee machine that sends it.

Comment: @Sarathsp Anyway, updated for a case where the data is available as a byte slice.

Comment: and endianess is part of the protocol