# How to convert unix timestap to hexadecimal

Tags: go, time

I have this snippet of C code that I'm trying to translate to Go:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>



int main()
{
    struct timeval started;
    int64_t ms;

    gettimeofday(&started, NULL);
    ms = (int64_t) started.tv_sec * 1000 + started.tv_usec / 1000;
    printf("Time: %011"PRIx64"\n", ms);

    return 0;
}
```

I've found how to convert unix time to millieseconds by using the below snippet:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Unix Time in ms: %d \n", time.Now().UnixNano() / 1000000)
}
```

However I'm having a hard time how to convert that number into hexadecimal (That somewhat resembles the output of the C code that I have.) I did find how to decode the hextime stamp using this [questions / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41692192/decode-hex-timestamp-probably-filetime). Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you read through the docs for the [fmt package](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/)?

Comment: Read wikipedia page on [number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number)s. Then the one on [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time). Then [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)

Comment: Lowercase hexadecimal representation with length 11 and zero padding is: `%011x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this should be the right solution:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    unix_time_ms := 1589664726314
    fmt.Printf("Hex Unixtime in MS: %x ,should equal 1721f66bd2a\n", unix_time_ms)
}
```

In C it should match this:

```
int main()
{
    int64_t unix_time_ms;
    unix_time_ms = 1589664726314;

    printf("Hex Unixtime in MS: %011"PRIx64"\n", unix_time_ms);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `'%XF'` to print hexadecimal in goalng. Like the following

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Unix Time in ms: %XF \n", time.Now().UnixNano() / 1000000)
}
```

Playground link [here](https://play.golang.org/p/28_d6Vftsje).

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `F` and `X` don't mix. You're also ignoring length, zero padding, and case.

Comment: @Marc I added a playground link and that clearly shows `F` and `X` mixes.

Comment: They mix in the sense that it runs, but you end up with `123234F` where the trailing F is not part of the number, it's just the F you're printing.